# How do I design a database for my Q&A website?

Tags: mysql, database, html, database-design, web

Every user can **ask questions** (in particular topics)

Users can **comment on the question**.

The question can have **multiple answers**.

Users can **comment on the answers**.

Comment: Show us what you have in mind.

Comment: it's basically a website like stackoverflow.

Comment: what design are you thinking of? so is not a "design my database for me" service"...

Comment: like, how many tables should I have. Should I separate the question and answers table and make a different table for every answer. I just need an abstract idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic design would be this:
Users table
Questions Table (with an fk to users - the author of the question)
Answers Table (with an fk to users and fk to questions)
comments Table (with an fk to users, a nullable fk to answers, and a nullable fk to questions).

Comment: don't you mean..
Answers Table (with an fk to users and fk to 'questions')

Comment: Yes, of course. sorry.